# Youtube "video zoomed in" bug, both in Chrome & Firefox, incognito mode or not. It works fine in other Linux & Windows though

Tags: gnome, video, youtube, html5

So, I have this bug in Youtube when viewing videos (HTML5), the "video window" contains a zoomed-in version of the video, so the bottom and right part of the video don't show, they are so to speak "outside".

[CRUCIAL SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvNZg.jpg)

INSTRUCTIONS FOR SCREENSHOT: Look at the bottom right corner of the "video window". The controls of the video are clearly cropped. The fullscreen button, is not even shown. The whole video is only partially shown, its cropped, because it's a unfamiliar video you might not realize this, but it's the truth, it's cropped.

**Ubuntu is 18.04.1 LTS, DEFAULT NORMAL INSTALLATION NOTHING FANCY**

**OS:** I don't have this problem in my Linux Mint, or Manjaro Cinnamon, or Windows 10. Only in Ubuntu.

**INCOGNITO MODE:** It doesn't depend on incognito mode or not at all.

**BROWSER:** Firefox+Chrome both have it.

**DESKTOP ENVIRONMENT:** Doesn't happen in KDE (same ubuntu) (plasma version 5.12.6). **HAPPENS ALSO IN WAYLAND. I HAVE GNOME 3.28.2**

If I press f (fullscreen shortcut in Youtube) twice, the problem fixes. But this is still a major issue too annoying. If one then, from the "fixed" tab, clicks on other videos appearing on the tab, such as the suggestions at the right, it's still fixed. But everytime one opens a new tab, it will have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

What I found is that the problem goes away as long as you set the Ubuntu Dock in auto-hide mode. Also, you can resize the window for a temporal fix.

Comment: 1) Your contributions are 100% checked true, they work, so I voted you up. 2)A) Setting Ubuntu Dock in auto hide mode is too much of a compromise, so I expect a solution that restricts so much. B)The resizing window, is very annoying to do. So in conclusion, we need a better solution, but know this, I'm very thankful for your contribution.